# Building a file in Linux

Tags: tls

I am a Windows user but I need to use a Linux tool. I am using Ubuntu. The tool's website [here](https://github.com/prbinu/tls-scan) provided a file named: `build-x86-64.sh` which I installed it. It then says all what you need is to run: `% ./build-x86-64.sh`. I tried `sudo ./build-x86-64.sh`. However, I get this error from Linux:

```
sudo: ./build-x86-64.sh: command not found
```

Note that I am in the right directory where I saved the `.sh` file. I also installed all the per-requisites:

```
autoconf
automake
libtool
pkg-config
gcc
```

Please, can you point to me what's wrong?

Comment: Also, downloaded files do not have the executable bit set. chmod +x file should make it easier to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

When using `sudo` to run a script using relative path syntax, it appears that many different error messages get hidden behind that "command not found" error message. I'd suggest re-running without the `sudo` to see what the actual error is.

Likely issues:

- My guess is the .sh file doesn't have the executable bit set (i.e., the OS hasn't been told it's a program). Try `chmod a+x build-x86-64.sh` from the same directory, to fix this. This should only need to be done once, and you may wish to look up "executable bit" at some point.
- Maybe the file isn't where you think it is? But, you say you're already in the same directory, so it should be fine...

Comment: It is likely/will be #1. The link is missing instructions on making the file executable.

Answer (score 1):

1. check your user running: `whoami`
2. check if you can execute the bash script running: `ls -la build-x86-64.sh`
3. check if your user can call sudo running: `sudo -l -U <whoami-output>`
4. check if your shell is able to run sudo running: `sudo whoami`

So:

- If the output of the point **1** or **4** is `root` the problem is relative at the permission about execution of build-x86-64.sh file, change it running : `sudo chmod 744 build-x86-64.sh` and then run again `sudo ./build-x86-64.sh`
- If the output of point **3** say you are able to run sudo , you have to put the directory where the file `build-x86-64.sh` is in the sudoers **secure_path** editing the `/etc/sudoers` file by running : `sudo visudo` and adding the /path-where-is-your-file.sh as explained [here](https://www.tecmint.com/run-shell-scripts-with-sudo-command-in-linux/). Be careful, editing that file can compromise the security of your device.

Hope it help ;)